# Why I can't use an mp4 video in <video> tag?

Tags: html, html5-video

I want to use a video as a background, and I'm using an HTML tag video, my code looks like this:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">Marine</div>
        <ul class="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Our products</li>
        <li>Achievements</li>
    </ul>
    </header>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="bg_video" controls>
        <source src="/assets/volny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
</body>
```

But it looks like this on my page:
[image]

It means "A video with supported format or mime-type is not found".
I'm not quite sure what's the problem here, because it's mp4 and I imported it from the correct folder. I'd be glad if you helped me figure out the problem

Comment: It's likely either the encoding of the video - an mp4 container can contain many video and audio codecs, but it has to be h264+aac or mp3 to play in most browsers - or how it's delivered by the server - sending incorrect headers, or not responding correctly to range headers.

Comment: i see, but how could i fix that?

Comment: if you can share a link to the video people can take a look and try to flag what is causing the browser not to be able to play it